# mysql CONCAT after WHERE?

Tags: mysql, subquery, concatenation

I have a query that manages attendance.  I wanted to add a feature that shows who's paid up for the month and who isn't.  It almost works.

```
SELECT
    students.sid,
    students.name,
    students.day,
    students.times,
    students.days,
    CONCAT(payments.year,'-', payments.forMonth) AS pdate
FROM students
LEFT JOIN payments
    ON students.sid = payments.sid
WHERE
    students.Active = 'Yes' AND
    students.day LIKE 'Tue%' AND
    payments.date = (SELECT date FROM payments WHERE students.sid = payments.sid AND
                     payments.payfor = 'tuition' ORDER BY payments.pid DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

The main trouble part is the *(SELECT date FROM)*
 subquery.  The CONCAT is grabbing the first value it gets from the *payments* table before the *payments.payfor* limiter in the *payments subquery* sets.  So, in the table snippet below, I get the *sk1* entry, instead of the correct *tuition* for *Dec*

```
pid     sid  amt    payfor  forMonth    year    date
1076    69  7000    tuition Dec         2017    2017-12-17
1074    69  4000     sk1    Sep         2017    2017-12-17
1046    69  7000    tuition Nov         2017    2017-11-23
```

Is there a way to get that *payments.date* subquery before or with the *CONCAT(payments.year,'-', payments.forMonth)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the condition related  to left join tables in the related  on clause otherwise if in where condition work as inner join and don't return he related  rows

```
  SELECT students.sid, students.name, students.day, students.times, students.days, 
  CONCAT(payments.year,'-', payments.forMonth) AS pdate 
  FROM students 
  LEFT JOIN payments ON students.sid = payments.sid  
        AND payments.date = (SELECT date 
          FROM payments 
          WHERE students.sid = payments.sid 
          AND payments.payfor = 'tuition' 
          ORDER BY payments.pid DESC LIMIT 1 
        )
  WHERE students.Active = 'Yes' 
  AND students.day LIKE 'Tue%'
```

and if you want only the tuition you should filter for this value too

```
  SELECT students.sid, students.name, students.day, students.times, students.days, 
  CONCAT(payments.year,'-', payments.forMonth) AS pdate 
  FROM students 
  LEFT JOIN payments ON students.sid = payments.sid  
        AND payments.date = (SELECT date 
          FROM payments 
          WHERE students.sid = payments.sid 
          AND payments.payfor = 'tuition' 
          ORDER BY payments.pid DESC LIMIT 1 
        ) 
        AND payments.payfor='tuition'

  WHERE students.Active = 'Yes' 
  AND students.day LIKE 'Tue%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still grabbing all the 'payments.payfor' instead of only 'tuition'

Comment: I guess we found it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.  I added

```
AND payments.payfor = 'tuition'
```

after the

```
students.Active = 'Yes' AND
students.day LIKE 'Tue%'
```

in my original query.  Then, everything worked as needed.